# Report model data source

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs

Does anybody know how i could use a linked server as a data source for a report model in SQL server 2008 r2? or how i could make this linked server a data source on a report model? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just put the datapull for the linked data source in a stored procedure and then access it from a "local" database?

Comment: How do I accomplish that?

Comment: @db7 via something like "create proc [procname] [arglist] as begin exec [linkedserver].[database].[schema].[remoteprocname] [arglist] end" ...

Answer (score 3):

The two ideas are unrelated

- A linked server is for SQL Server to other database server connections *at the database level*.
- In SSRS you have DataSets which point to a database

There are some cases where the DataSet calls a SQL Server database that uses a linked server: but I suspect you aren't that far yet.

If you think you need to use a "linked server" to call one database *only* to get data from *another database*, then why not call the other database directly. And stop thinking of linked servers

Comment: The linked server is a Linux box.

Comment: @db7 it doesn't matter. If you can set up a linked server then can set it up as a datasource in SSRS